# wp_insert_post_data filter hook identify current action

Tags: filters, wp-update-post

I have this function to set the title of a wordpress post which works properly for saving / updating posts. The major issue is that the function stops posts being deleted (it removes the title but the post still exists).

Is there a way to identify if the action is a delete post rather than save / update post and obviously i don't return the $data if a delete action?

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'updatetitle' ) , '99', 1 ); 

public function updatetitle($data) {

    if($data['post_type'] != $property->post_name || !$_POST[${$this->active_class_var_name}->noncefield] ):
        return $data;
    endif;  

    if($_POST['address'] && $_POST[$property->noncefield]):
        $data['post_title']= ucfirst (sanitize_text_field($_POST['address'])).' '.ucfirst (sanitize_text_field($_POST['town'])).' '.ucfirst (sanitize_text_field($_POST['county']) );
    endif;

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but seems maybe $data['post_status'] would be set to 'trash' at that point.  If so, then you could just do something like...

```
if ($data['post_status'] == 'trash') { return $data; }
```

...before the other manipulations.

**EDIT**

That code should work then - but needs to be at top of the function, like...

```
public function updatetitle($data) {

    if ($data['post_status'] == 'trash') { return $data; }

    if($data['post_type'] != $property->post_name || !$_POST[${$this->active_class_var_name}->noncefield] ):
        return $data;
    endif;  

    if($_POST['address'] && $_POST[$property->noncefield]):
        $data['post_title']= ucfirst(sanitize_text_field($_POST['address'])).' '.
            ucfirst (sanitize_text_field($_POST['town'])).' '.
            ucfirst (sanitize_text_field($_POST['county']) );
    endif;

    return $data;
}
```

Your function in that case would simply return back the $data without making any other modifications to it.

Comment: the post status == trash evals to true but it still is the same, the title is removed but the post still exists :(

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) hook instead of `wp_insert_post_data`.

It should solve your problem

Comment: Im not sure you can modify the post data from there?